# how to call query call back data to data attribute select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

```
$('#placeSelect').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
     data: function(query) {
     queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);
     },
     matcher: function (term, text) {if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0){return true;}return false;}
     });


        function queryData{!randomJsIden}(query){
           Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
       '{!$RemoteAction.AutoCompleteV2_Con.getData}','{!sObjVal}','{!labelFieldVar}','{!valueFieldVar}',query.term,
                     function(result, event){
                      //if success
                         if(event.status){ 
                            var data = {results:[{ id: 1, text: "Ford"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Dodge"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Mercedes" },
            { id: 4, text: "Jaguar"   }]}
                             query.callback( data);                           
                         }   
                     }, 
                      {escape: true}
                );
            } 
    </script>
```

How to initialize query call back data to data attribute in select2 .
I cannot use data directly .In above example i am using sample data .

```
query : function(query){
     queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);
     }
```

I want to replace this by data attribute like this : the below one is not working

```
data : function(query){
     queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);
     }
```

here is the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnf8j/303/

Let me know any ideas from you

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues in your code

1. you cannot name a function using flower braces as it is reserved notation symbol in javascript `function queryData{!randomJsIden}(query)`, instead name it as `function queryData(query){ ... }`
2. if your adding a callback for data of your select2 then you need to return that data constructed from `queryData()` function.

   ```
   data: function(query) {
     return queryData(query);
   },
   function queryData(query){
      ...
      return data;
   }
   ```
3. If i'am not wrong,data is sourced to `select2` via asynchronous call inside `queryData()`, which means the data is returned at unpredictable time,so you need to restrict the user from accessing the `select2` component until data is feeded to it.
   which means you either need to prefetch the data or disable the `select2` field until data is returned from remote call.

[Working Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Lnf8j/306/)